# Creating Strip Map Index using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, strip-map, map-series

The Strip Map Index Features tool is listed amongst the [Tools that are not available in ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/appendices/unavailable-tools.htm) at version 2.2.

A workaround when needing a strip map index to be created, with an Angle field being populated so that each page can be rotated correctly, would be to use the [Strip Map Index Features tool from ArcGIS Desktop](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/creating-strip-map-index-features.htm) but is anyone aware of a workaround for creating a strip map index on a machine when only ArcGIS Pro (with its ArcPy) is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just revisited [Tools that are not available in ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/appendices/unavailable-tools.htm) and found that whilst the strip map tool is still unavailable in version 2.2, there now exists a potential workaround for some workflows.

From the page:

> The tool [Generate Rectangles Along Lines](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/generate-rectangles-along-lines.htm) can be used as a replacement
>   for the Strip Map Index Features tool in some workflows.

The tool is in the sampling toolbox and is available for all license levels. The documentation for that tool states that it

> creates a series of rectangular polygons that follow a single linear
>   feature or a group of linear features.

This tool will create an angle field which meets your requirements.

It may be relevant to point out that it cannot be used on features which participate in a geometric network.  For such features you may need to export them out to a separate feature class.